# Clean function in excel

Tags: excel

When i use clean function to remove the non-printable characters from the below content "2017 and Houston" gets append together like below. Can anyone please provide a solution for this?

**Before clean function:**

"Published April 3, 2017
HOUSTON ? A 48-year-old California resident has entered a guilty plea to trafficking in counterfeit labels and packaging, announced Acting U.S. Attorney Abe Martinez."

**After clean function:**

Published April 3, **2017HOUSTON**  A 48-year-old California resident has entered a guilty plea to trafficking in counterfeit labels and packaging, announced Acting U.S. Attorney Abe Martinez.

[Refer below image for actual content with non-printable characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZFrR.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to clean up in this text? The before version looks clean to me? Also how are you extracting that text from the image?

Comment: When i copied the string from the question and checed it, clean just works fine for me

Comment: Clean removed "Alt + Enter" you can insert space after 2017 before using Clean

Answer (score 0):

There is a carriage return and/or line feed in your string and `Clean()` is removing it (thanks @yass for catching that).

You can use formula `=Substitute` to swap this out to a space so `Clean()` won't clean it. If it's just a line feed character (caused by Alt+Enter in Excel) then:

```
=CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), " "))
```

If it's a Carriage Return/Line Feed combo which is typical in Windows:

```
=CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(13) & CHAR(10), " "))
```